# spring boot app shutting down without error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot application with mysql, web, jpa as dependencies. I have configured the `application.properties` file with the database properties. The log is attached for more details below:

```
2018-08-16 10:02:00.746  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.classpath.CrudApplication            : Starting CrudApplication on LAPTOP-MAI0FJBD with PID 10472 (C:\Users\classpath\packt\Downloads\crud\target\classes started by classpath in C:\Users\classpath\packt\Downloads\crud)
2018-08-16 10:02:00.748  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.classpath.CrudApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-16 10:02:00.876  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17bd80f6: startup date [Thu Aug 16 10:02:00 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-16 10:02:02.107  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$437af157] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-16 10:02:02.370  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-08-16 10:02:02.572  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-08-16 10:02:02.602  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-16 10:02:02.616  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-08-16 10:02:02.670  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-08-16 10:02:02.671  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-08-16 10:02:02.708  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-08-16 10:02:02.847  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2018-08-16 10:02:03.377  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-16 10:02:04.183  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-08-16 10:02:04.206  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-16 10:02:04.207  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-08-16 10:02:04.210  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-16 10:02:04.221  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.classpath.CrudApplication            : Started CrudApplication in 3.814 seconds (JVM running for 4.411)
2018-08-16 10:02:04.225  INFO 10472 --- [      Thread-10] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17bd80f6: startup date [Thu Aug 16 10:02:00 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-16 10:02:04.228  INFO 10472 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-08-16 10:02:04.228  INFO 10472 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-08-16 10:02:04.229  INFO 10472 --- [      Thread-10] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-16 10:02:04.230  INFO 10472 --- [      Thread-10] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-08-16 10:02:04.233  INFO 10472 --- [      Thread-10] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have created the git repository and uploaded my code onto Github - [Link to Github repo](https://github.com/classpath-dev/crud-api.git)

I am also attaching the `pom.xml` for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.classpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>crud</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How should I be debugging this error. Kindly let me know as there is lot of magic going on here.

Comment: How you are starting you server?

Comment: @Pramod running the CrudApplication as java program from IntelliJ Idea IDE.

Comment: Can you please share the pom.xml

Comment: @zilcuanu run this as maven project with `spring-boot:run` as the goal.

Comment: @Pramod how to do that on IntelliJ Idea IDE?

Comment: What is the memory of your server where the application is running?

Comment: Application is running fine with only one change in application.properties file logging.level.root==DEBUG

Comment: The embedded container that I would expect to start due to your use of the web starter has not started. Have you configured your app so that it is not a web app, perhaps? If not, the condition evaluation report will tell you why components have and have not been auto-configured. It will be output on startup if you start your application with `--debug`.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes. The application is not starting with web. I used Spring initializer with web, jpa,mysql dependencies. How to configure it to run on a container?

Comment: check if your mysql server is running.

Comment: @Skenia, I think application should have thrown error if mysql server would have been down and application tries to connect to same.

Comment: @Pramod Maybe he disabled the logs for error/warn, I checked his source code on my machine and is working fine.

Comment: @zilcuanu The configuration that you have should work. Can you please start your application with `--debug` and update your question with the output of the resulting condition evaluation report?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have run the spring boot app in debug mode and configured the location of the log file as `application.log` inside the root directory. I have committed the log file. I do not see any error or warning. Link for the application.log file - https://github.com/classpath-dev/crud-api/blob/master/application.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition evaluation report in the application log shows that the embedded servlet container hasn't been configured as `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` is not on the classpath:

```
ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration:
  Did not match:
     - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.ServletRequest' (OnClassCondition)
```

It should be on the classpath as you have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` which pulls in `tomcat-embed-core` that contains all of the Servlet API classes. The application log also shows that `C:\Users\classpath\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.32\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar` is on the classpath.

For the jar file to be on the classpath and a class that it contains not to be found, the jar file must be corrupted. This can happen when Maven downloads the jar. Try deleting the `C:\Users\classpath\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.32\` directory and rebuilding your application. This will cause Maven to download a new copy of the jar and, hopefully, to not corrupt it this time.

Comment: This worked. Nice troubleshooting  and for letting me know, how to crack these kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I was able to solve this problem. I deleted the repository directory inside `.m2` and build the whole project once again. This time, it worked.